# How do I reference LaTeX help in my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, latex-misc

Basically I'm trying to reference properly for my dissertation, and I wondered if there's a manual somewhere I can quote - I can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Academic standards do not require you to cite the typesetting software you composed your dissertation with. It's a tool you used, not an intellectual input to your work. You wouldn't cite the manufacturer of your printer either.

Of course the opposite is true if you are writing a dissertation about computer typesetting.

Your question though has one more aspect that is of some generic interest: It is a bit strange to acknowledge a software by citing a manual you had never consulted while using the software. It might be more appropriate to cite the software as such, and not a manual.